# What is difference between Wait state & Bus idle machine cycle in Case of 8085 Microprocessor?

Tags: microcontroller, microprocessor, assembly

I have Understood that Wait State provides extra time for slow devices by making ready signal low. Bus idle is a machine without performing any Read/Write Signal, I am able to figure out some differences but confused about their functionality as both provides some Delay only.

Comment: You might need to add some context. Not all CPUs and memories are exactly the same, are you thinking of specific hardware?

Answer (score 1):

The difference is *when* the delay occurs: In a "wait state", the delay occurs *during* a memory (or I/O) access cycle, giving the addressed device more time to respond. A "bus idle" state occurs *between* access cycles, and has no bearing on the addressed devices, other than giving them time to perform internal functions such as memory refresh.